# Maximum value of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let, $a$ be a fixed positive real number. Consider the set $$S=\{x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}:x_{i}\ge0(1\le i\le n),\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=a\}.$$

Find the maximum value of $S$. I know that the answer is $\bigl(\dfrac{a}{n}\bigr)^{n}$. But how I can prove it? I tried it but I can't proceed it anyway.

Comment: You have used the multivariable calculus tag, which suggests you have considered this as a standard continuous maximization problem.  What difficulty did you find in such an approach?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x_i>a/n>x_j$.  Replace them with $a/n$ and $x_i+x_j-a/n$.  Can you show the product goes up?  Repeat until all the numbers equal $a/n$

Comment: I can't understand it. Please clear..

Comment: @Panja.S.: If you increase the smaller $x_j$ by an amount $\delta$ and decrease the larger by the same amount, the product increases ( if $\delta$ is not too large). The clever thing is to make one of them equal the average, thus being able to focus on the others.